# How can I define roll over file size in Azure Data Factory for Blob sink?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I want to copy a large Database table to Azure Blob Storage, but I want each file in the Azure Blob Storage to not be more than a certain size. Is there a way in Azure Data Factory to define such roll over size? Because I can't see any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Azure does not provide limit per container. The Azure provides Maximum number of blocks in a block blob or append blob is (50,000 blocks), Maximum size of a block in a block blob is (4000 MiB) and Maximum size of a block blob  is (50,000 X 4000 MiB (approximately 190.7 TiB)).  As Per your requirement, You have to restrict the certain data in large Database table before moving to azure blob. Pls refer from [Azure subscription limits and quotas - Azure Resource Manager | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#storage-limits)